# Clustering and confusion matrix

Tags: data-mining, bigdata

Here is the problem
The initial four cluster partition {c1, c2, c3, c4} for the text collection is provided by this link [text vs cluster](http://userpages.umbc.edu/~kogan/teaching/m710/15fall/project/list.txt). Assuming that
the ground-truth partition is given by

```
cacm texts belong to cluster1
cisi texts belong to cluster2
cran texts belong to cluster3
med texts belong to cluster4
```

build the confusion matrix (CM) for the partition provided. That is build a 4X4 matrix whose row i shows distribution of ci elements
among cluster1, cluster2, cluster3, and cluster4. For example the first row is computed as follows:
CM11=|c1∩cluster1|,  CM12=|c1∩cluster2|,  CM13=|c1∩cluster3|, and CM14=|c1∩cluster4| 
I understand the problem just not sure how to code it up.
I was thinking along the lines of this

```
//open text file
fileID = fopen('list.txt');
C = textscan(fileID,'%s %s');
fclose(fileID);
```

What this does is it orders the names as $C\{1\}\{j\}$is the file name and $C\{2\}\{j\}$ is the cluster name.
By the way I am using Matlab

Comment: Where is your data stored? If it is a SQL database then you should just group by the cluster and concept to get the confusion matrix. Pandas his a similar functionality and you can read quite easily most data sources into it.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you clustering results are store in R. You have the partition id *part_id* and the real *clust_id*, here in a small example

```
df <- read.table(text = "obj,  part_id, clust_id 
X, 1, 1
Y, 2, 2
Z, 3, 3 
U, 1, 3
V, 2, 3
W, 2, 3"
```

Than the **table** will do the work for you

```
> table(df[,c("part_id","clust_id")])

       clust_id
part_id 1 2 3
      1 1 0 1
      2 0 1 2
      3 0 0 1
```

**UPDATE**

For completeness you may also use SQL (as proposed in a comment), a sample query is shown below on a table identical to the data-frame above.

You will see imediately, that there is a limitation because you must define the exact column list in the query - so the query must be adjusted based on the cluster / partition list.

```
with clust_agg as (
select part_id, clust_id, count(*) cnt from clust
group by part_id, clust_id
)
select * from clust_agg
pivot(sum(cnt) clust  for (clust_id) in 
     (1 as "1",
      2 as "2",
      3 as "3"))
order by 1;
, header = TRUE, sep=",")
```

.

```
   PART_ID    1_CLUST    2_CLUST    3_CLUST
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1                     1 
         2                     1          2 
         3                                1
```